# In Rails, POST, render another action converts to a GET in the same action, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, action, render

I have some extra, non-Restful actions in a restful controller. One action responds to a GET, with a form, the form does a POST/PATCH (I've tried both), to another action. If the requirements aren't met, then the method that responds to a POST adds error messages to the model, and renders the first action, exactly like edit and update, or new and create. But...

If the second action has to render back to the first action I see in my logs that it does it right, but then immediately afterwards, there's a request to GET the second action, which obviously fails because there's no GET path to the second action. The end result is that I don't get errors passed down to the form. Why is this? What could be causing it? It's driving me nuts.

Here's the code

```html
def finish_subscription
    unless user_signed_in?
      store_location_for :user,request.path
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    else
      @user ||=User.find_by(subscribe_token: params[:token])
      authorize! :finish_subscription,@user
      @user.accepted_t_and_c = false
    end
  end

  def confirm_subscription
    @user=User.find_by(subscribe_token: params[:token])
    authorize! :confirm_subscription,@user
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      o = @user.orders.create
      o.build_a_default_subscription
      o.save
      session[:active_order_id] = o.id
      @user.subscribe_token = nil
      @user.save
      redirect_to pay_via_braintree_path    
    else
       # I've tried all combinations of render action: 'finish_subscription', render :finish_subscription & etc
      render 'finish_subscription'
    end
  end
```

This is what I see in my logs;-

```
Started POST "/users/confirm_subscription/d6bb1ffbe56207b6c6864e739e9a455b"
```

When that fails on validation errors it gets to the line

```
render 'finish_subscription'
```

which responds with ;-

```
Rendered users/finish_subscription.html.haml within layouts/application (2.4ms)
```

Which is what I expect. But then, immediately afterwards ...

```
Started GET "/users/confirm_subscription/d6bb1ffbe56207b6c6864e739e9a455b"
```

WTF!!! Of course that fails because there's no GET route for that action.

Why why why is this happening? And why is it happening on a sunny Sunday afternoon when I've got better things to do?

Comment: can you add the full logs so we can see what's going on, instead of just a couple of lines with some commentary?

Comment: Watch out for things like image tags with a blank src (which would result in the browser doing a get to the current URL)